# odoo xpath add existing element inside element

Tags: xpath, odoo, qweb

I am trying to add existing division of Odoo product template in a new division. for that, I can do the "replace" of the whole division. and add my custom division.
for example, here is default Odoo template section with the div.

```
<section t-attf-class="container mt8 oe_website_sale" id="product_detail">
    <div class="row" id="odoo_default_row">
    </div>
</section>
```

and I wanted to add odoo_default_row div in my custom div element. like

```
<section t-attf-class="container mt8 oe_website_sale" id="product_detail">
    <div id="my_custom_div">
        <div class="row" id="odoo_default_row">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

what is the best way to add existing division in the custom division despite using xpath replace?

Answer (score 0):

We can replace whole div element using "replace" attribute. With these, we can freely design custom div element.

Try with following code:

```
<div id="odoo_default_row" position="replace">
    <!-- Design your div element as per your requirement-->
</div>
```

NOTE:

As per my understanding with your situation is that "inside" attribute will not work.